# Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\hoc\get_session.php on line 2

Tags: php, variables, session, undefined

### First page

```
<?php 
session_start(); // put ahead all html tags and echo commands and print.

$_SESSION["username"] = 'admin';
echo '<a href="get_session.php">see session</a>';
?>
```

### Second page

```
<?php
    if( $_SESSION["username"] == 'admin' ) {
        echo 'Hello '. $_SESSION["username"] . ' You are adminstrator on this page';
    } else {
        echo 'You can not accesss';
    }
?>
```

### Question

When I click on the link session then I get :

> Undefined variable: _SESSION

I have no idea why.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your second file at the start `session_start();`

like that:

```
 <?php
session_start();
    if( $_SESSION["username"] == 'admin' )
    {
        echo 'Hello '. $_SESSION["username"] . ' You are adminstrator on this page';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'You can not accesss';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put session_start(); at the begin of the second page.